# Como é que eu posso correr um trigger que atualize automaticamente uma tabela quando um atributo é atualizado?

Tags: sql, oracle, trigger, cursor

```
Create OR Replace TRIGGER filme_log
before Update OF custo On filme
Referencing New As New Old As Old
For Each Row 
Begin 
Insert into filme_log Values(:new.nome_original, :old.custo, :new.custo, sysdate);
END;
```

Este é o meu trigger e isto está a funcionar.

```
Begin
Update filme set custo = 9876546 where nome_original = 'UP';
Commit;
Declare
Cursor filme_log_cur is
Select nomeF,custo_old,custo_new, data
From filme_log;
nomeF_cur filme_log.nomeF%type;
custo_old_cur filme_log.custo_old%type;
custo_new_cur filme_log.custo_new%type;
data_cur filme_log.data%type;
Begin
Open filme_log_cur;
Loop Fetch filme_log_cur into nomeF_cur, custo_old_cur, custo_new_cur, data_cur;
EXIT WHEN filme_log_cur%notfound;
DBMS_Output.put_line('Dados inseridos em Filme_log:');
DBMS_Output.put_line(nomeF_cur || '  ' ||custo_old_cur || '  ' ||custo_new_cur || '  ' || data_cur);
END LOOP;
END;
```

E eu estou a tentar correr este trigger mas não consigo perceber porque que não está a funcionar.

Comment: João, você está no Stack Overflow em Português, traduza a sua pergunta por favor.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow **in Portuguese**. As the name implies, the official language used here is Portuguese. So, can you please translate your question? If you prefer, you may also ask this same question in [the English StackOverflow site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow **em português**. Tal como o nome sugere, o idioma oficial usado aqui é o português. Assim sendo, você poderia por favor traduzir sua pergunta? Caso prefira, você também pode fazer essa mesma pergunta no [site em inglês do StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Qual banco de dados você esta utilizando?

Comment: Estamos a usar o ORACLE.

Answer (score 1):

O problema pode ser que a trigger esteja desabilitada.

Primeiro verifique se a trigger esta habilitada usando:

SELECT STATUS FROM USER_TRIGGERS WHERE TRIGGER_NAME = 'filme_log';

Se estiver desabilitada, habilite usando:

ALTER TRIGGER filme_log ENABLE;